# Juntar controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jade

Eu tenho este controller que manda um notificação normal de Error ou Success

```
 $scope.add = function () {
        if(!$scope.name || !$scope.url ){
            $scope.success = null;
            return $scope.error = 'Preencha todos os campos.'
        }else{

            var newGroup = {
                name: $scope.name,
                url: $scope.url
            }

            $http.post("/api/group/add", newGroup).then(function (response) {
                if(response.data.err){
                    $scope.error = response.data.err;
                    $scope.success = null;
                }else{
                    getGroupByAccess();
                    clearForm();
                    userSessionService.updateUserMenu();
                    $scope.success = response.data.msg;
                    $scope.error = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

E tenho esse controller que manda uma notificação mais organizada

```
var notifyApp = angular.module('notifyApp',['angular-growl','ngAnimate']);

notifyApp.controller('notifyCtrl',['$scope','growl',function($scope,growl){
    $scope.showError = function(){
        growl.error('This is a error mesage.',{title: 'Error!'});
    }
    $scope.showSuccess = function(){
        growl.success('This is a success mesage.',{title: 'Success!'});
    }
}]);
```

E essa aqui é a chamada

```
.content(ng-controller="groupsController")
    .alert.alert-danger(ng-show='error' class='ng-hide')
      span{{error}}
        button.close(type='button', aria-label='Close' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Close' ng-click='close()') x
    .alert.alert-success(ng-show='success' class='ng-hide')
      span{{success}}
        button.close(type='button', aria-label='Close' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Close' ng-click='close()') x
```

Como posso usar esse segundo controller no primeiro, lembrando que está tudo importando e funcionando, só preciso entender como seria feito e chamado

Comment: Crie um serviço para armazenar todos os seus processos de notificação. Isso permitirá a você manter o código mais limpo e extensível.

Answer (score 1):

Na definição do primeiro controller você pode injetar o segundo controller:

```
notifyApp.controller('primeiroCtrl', ['$scope', 'notifyCtrl', function($scope, notifyCtrl) {
```

(não veio o código de criação do primeiro controller na sua pergunta)